# (ssh tunnel?) Access remote server with private IP through a *DIFFERENT* server with public IP

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, remote, ssh-tunnel

Let's assume the following hosts:

- *localhost* : my laptop
- *remoteserver* : a server with a public IP which runs a SSH server.
- *private.remoteserver* : a server with a private IP which is only accessible from *remoteserver*.

I don't have `sudo` access to *remoteserver*, so I can't make changes with the root user.

**The question is**: Is it possible to access a port on *private.remoteserver* from *remoteserver*, in a single command?

I've played around a bit with ssh tunnels without luck. It would like to create an SSH alias to *private.remoteserver* as [described in this article](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html).

For example, I'd like to run from localhost:

```
curl http://private.remoteserver:8080/
```

to connect to port 8080 on private.remoteserver. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't show us what you've tried so far, but something as simple as this should work:

```
ssh -L 8080:private.remoteserver:8080 remoteserver
```

Which would then let you run:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

...which due to the port forwarding we just set up would actually connect to port `8080` on `private.remoteserver`.

If you want to be able to directly access `http://private.remoteserver:8080/` from your client, you'll need to (a) set up some sort of proxy and (b) configure curl (or other software) to use the proxy.  You can set up a `SOCKS5` proxy with `ssh` using the `-D` option:

```
ssh -D 1080 remoteserver
```

And then you can:

```
curl --socks5-hostname http://private.remoteserver:8080/
```

Most web browsers (Firefox, Chrome) can also be configured to operate with a `SOCKS5` proxy.  If you search for "ssh dynamic forwarding" you'll find lots of good documentation, including [this article from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Dynamic_Port_Forwarding).

Comment: Thanks, the command ssh -L 18080:private.remoteserver:8080 -f -N user@remoteserver allows to me to curl on port 18080, but do is there a way to avoid to run 1 command like this (or 1 proxy per service) for each port I want to access on private.remoteserver?

Comment: Sure, that's what the dynamic proxy is all about.  Take a look at the docs I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but I have to specify the proxy in all applications. I'd like to create an alias in /etc/hosts and get all traffic to this host fowarded through ssh tunnel.

Comment: I accept your answer, as it is valid for the question I originely asked. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I solved my problem with [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle):

```
sshuttle --dns -HN -r user@remoteserver
```

No other proxy configuration required, then I can access any ports of the private IP :

```
curl http://private:8080/
```